# libcurl automatically replacing line feed with line feed + carriage return

Tags: c++, codeblocks, libcurl

As title says when downloading something and saving libcurl replacing all the LF with LF + CR. It is fine for the text documents. But for binary it is a disaster. I already tried

```
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_CRLF, 0L);
```

How to disable this thing. I'm running on windows and curl 7.40.0

```
#include <iostream>
#include <curl/curl.h>

using namespace std;

CURL *curl;
CURLcode res;

size_t file_write_callback(char *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void *userdata)
{
    fwrite(ptr,size,nmemb,(FILE *)userdata);
    return nmemb;
}

int main(void)
{
    FILE * pFile;
    pFile = fopen ("myfile.png","w");

    curl = curl_easy_init();
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.dilushan.tk/Media/128px_feed.png");
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1L);

    if (pFile!=NULL)
    {
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, pFile);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, file_write_callback);
        res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
    }
    fclose (pFile);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

libburl is not the culprit, but underlying system library is. Because Windows has a notion of binary files where no conversion should occur, and text files where end of lines are represented as CrLf (`\r\n`) on disk and only `\n` in C or C++.

And the fix is quite easy : simply use `b` (for binary) in mode string in `open` :

```
pFile = fopen ("myfile.png","wb");
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out my silly mistake. That fixed my issue